# When I change from document.getElementById to document.querySelectorAll the script breaks

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML canvas snow script that I'm trying to get working on my site. I'm trying to get the script to work on every canvas element with the class `canvas-snow`. So when I changed `document.getElementById` to `document.querySelectorAll` the script breaks.

My HTML:

```
<a class="featured-image-link"></a>
<canvas id="canvas-1" class="canvas-snow">
</canvas>
<a class="featured-image-link"></a>
<canvas id="canvas-2" class="canvas-snow">
</canvas>
<a class="featured-image-link"></a>
<canvas id="canvas-3" class="canvas-snow">
</canvas>
```

My CSS:

```
.featured-image-link {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #666;
}

 body {
  background: #000;
}
```

My Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas-snow");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var particlesOnScreen = 245;
var particlesArray = [];
var el = document.querySelector(".featured-image-link");
var w,h;
w = canvas.width = el.clientWidth;
h = canvas.height = el.clientHeight;

function random(min, max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
};

function clientResize(ev){
    w = canvas.width = el.clientWidth;
    h = canvas.height = el.clientHeight;
};
window.addEventListener("resize", clientResize);

function createSnowFlakes() {
    for(var i = 0; i < particlesOnScreen; i++){
        particlesArray.push({
            x: Math.random() * w,  
            y: Math.random() * h,  
            opacity: Math.random(),  
            speedX: random(-11, 11),  
            speedY: random(7, 15),    
            radius:random(0.5, 4.2),
        })
    }
};

function drawSnowFlakes(){
    for(var i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++){    
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(  
            particlesArray[i].x,   
            particlesArray[i].y,   
            0,                     
            particlesArray[i].x,   
            particlesArray[i].y,   
            particlesArray[i].radius  
            );

            gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255," + particlesArray[i].opacity + ")");  // white
            gradient.addColorStop(.8, "rgba(210, 236, 242," + particlesArray[i].opacity + ")");  // bluish
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(237, 247, 249," + particlesArray[i].opacity + ")");   // lighter bluish

            ctx.beginPath(); 
            ctx.arc(
            particlesArray[i].x,  
            particlesArray[i].y,  
            particlesArray[i].radius,  
            0,                         
            Math.PI*2,                 
            false                     
            );

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;   
        ctx.fill();                 
    }
};

function moveSnowFlakes(){
    for (var i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
        particlesArray[i].x += particlesArray[i].speedX;     
        particlesArray[i].y += particlesArray[i].speedY;     

        if (particlesArray[i].y > h) {                                                                               
            particlesArray[i].x = Math.random() * w * 1.5;
            particlesArray[i].y = -50;
        }
    }
};

function updateSnowFall  () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawSnowFlakes();
    moveSnowFlakes();
};

setInterval(updateSnowFall,50);
createSnowFlakes();

});
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a *collection*, not an element, you need to iterate through each element of the collection

Comment: `document.querySelector(".featured-image-link")[0]`, `document.querySelector(".featured-image-link")[1]` etc. Also please do not mark jQuery code as JavaScript or if you're going to ask a JavaScript question do not include jQuery syntax.